# FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, reactjs

[image]

Basically, I try to post formdata  to my own api. I think I have got a issue with array of objects.

```
   const handleSubmit =  async e => {

        e.preventDefault()


        try{

            const formData = new FormData()
            formData.append('title',formState.inputs.title.value)
            formData.append('image',formState.inputs.image.value)
            formData.append('ingredients',JSON.stringify(ingredientData))
            formData.append("instructions",JSON.stringify(instructionData))
            formData.append('readyInMinutes',formState.inputs.readyInMinutes.value)
            formData.append('servings',formState.inputs.servings.value)
            formData.append('price',formState.inputs.price.value)
            formData.append('creator',auth.userId)

            const responseData = await axios.post(
                process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL+'/recipes/new',
                 formData,{
                 headers: {Authorization : `Bearer ${auth.token}`} })
                 console.log(responseData)
          }

        catch(err){
           console.log(err.message)
        }
    }
```

I can send this to my own api. My server refused to send response.

This recipe controller.js

```
const createRecipe = async (req, res, next) =>{                                 //We create a new recipe
  const errors = validationResult(req)
  if(!errors.isEmpty()){
    const error = new HttpError('Invalid inputs passed, please check your data. 2',422)
    return next(error)
  }
  const {title,ingredients,instructions,readyInMinutes,servings, ratings,comments, nutrients,price} = req.body
  console.log(req.file)
   let newIngredients = JSON.parse(ingredients)
   let newInstructions = JSON.parse(instructions)
   const myIngredients = []
   let myInstructions = []
   console.log(newIngredients)
   console.log(newInstructions)

   for(let i = 0;newIngredients.length;i++){
    let createIngredient = new Ingredient({
      name:newIngredients.name,
      amount:newIngredients.amount,
      measure:newIngredients.measure
    })
    myIngredients.push(createIngredient)
   }
   for(let i = 0;i<newInstructions.length;i++){
    let createInstruction = new Instruction({
      content:newInstructions.content
    })
    myInstructions.push(createInstruction)
   }
   console.log(myInstructions)
   console.log(myIngredients)

  const createdRecipe = new Recipe({
    title,
    image:req.file.path,
    ingredients:myIngredients,
    instructions:myInstructions,
    readyInMinutes,
    servings,
    price,
    creator:req.userData.userId,
    ratings:[],
    comments:[],
    nutrients:[],

  })
  let user
  try{
    user = await User.findById(req.userData.userId)                             // When we add a new recipe we need user's recipes array,too.That's why We need user who add this recipe.
  }
  catch(err){
    const errors = new HttpError('Something went wrong',500)
    return next(error)
  }
  if(!user){
    const error = new HttpError('This user does not exist',422)
    return next(error)
  }
  try{                                                                          // We need to do this.Because When we add a new recipe that affect user's recipes array, too.We want to make sure to add this recipe both collections.
      const sess = await mongoose.startSession()
      sess.startTransaction()
      await  createdRecipe.save({session:sess})
      user.recipes.push(createdRecipe)
      await user.save({session:sess})
      await sess.commitTransaction()
  }
  catch(err){
    const error = new HttpError('Created recipe failed, please create again 2',500)

    return next(error)
  }
  res.status(201).json({recipe:createdRecipe})
}
```

I get those arrays and apply Json.parse() to convert json string to js object.

Recipe model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator')
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
const ingredientSchema = require("./Ingredient").schema;
const instructionSchema = require("./Instruction").schema;


const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxLength: 280
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true, // this adds `createdAt` and `updatedAt` properties
  toJSON: {
    // whenever the comment is converted to JSON
    transform(doc, json) {
      delete json.__v
      return json
    }
  }
})




const recipeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  image:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  ingredients:[ingredientSchema],
  instructions:[instructionSchema],
  readyInMinutes:{
    type:Number,
    required:true
  },
  servings:{
    type:Number,
    required:true
  },
  price:{
    type:Number,
    required:true
  },
  creator:{
    type:mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    required:true,
    ref:'User'
  },
  ratings:[{
    point:{
      type:Number,
      required:true
    }
  }],
  comments:[commentSchema],
  nutrients:[{
    name:{
      type:String,
      required:true
    },
    amount:{
      type:Number,
      required:true
    }
  }],



})
recipeSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator)                                            //We plugin wiht mogooseValidator with our schema.
module.exports = mongoose.model('Recipe',recipeSchema)                          //We called User model with recipeSchema
```

I use mongodb for database.

Answer (score 0):

I did silly mistakes in for loop :)

```
for(let i = 0;newIngredients.length;i++){
    let createIngredient = new Ingredient({
      name:newIngredients.name,
      amount:newIngredients.amount,
      measure:newIngredients.measure
    })
```